# WMIC output in a batch script

Tags: wmic

This is pretty straight forward but after much Googling and experimenting, I cannot find the answer.
I will use this as an example and then I can apply it to other scripts I am writing.
When I run this command

```
wmic cpu get name > C:\Temp\PCINFO_TEMp\core.txt
```

I get this:

Name
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10310U CPU @ 1.70GHz

Is there a way to get the Intel info without getting Name?
I have tried Findstr and find and it wouldnt work.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unicode output of **WMIC** encoded with UTF-16 LE with BOM (byte order mark) can be filtered with two **FOR** loops to get just the wanted data written into an ASCII encoded text file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe CPU GET Name /VALUE') do for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%J in ("%%I") do >"C:\Temp\PCINFO_TEMP\core.txt" echo %%~J
endlocal
```

The usage of just one **FOR** loop as follows does not really work.

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe CPU GET Name /VALUE') do >"C:\Temp\PCINFO_TEMP\core.txt" echo %%I
```

The reason is that the Windows command processor has a problem on processing the UTF-16 encoded output of **WMIC** and would write the data with two carriage returns and a line-feed into the text file instead of just carriage return + line-feed. This wrong line termination issue is avoided by using two **FOR /F** loops.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic cpu /?`
- `wmic cpu get /?`